# Angularjs with jquery auto complete not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying for the past 5 hours without success...
 Here is the code..

In View:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="foo" auto-complete/>Foo = {{foo}}
```

In controller:

```
    myapp.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {
            elem.autocomplete({
                source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), //from your service
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    scope.foo= ui.item.label;
                    scope.$apply;
                },
                change:function (event, ui) {
                    if (ui.item === null) {
                        scope.foo = null;
                    }
                },
                minLength: 2
            });
        }
    };
});

    myapp.factory('autoCompleteDataService', [function() {
    return {
        getSource: function() {
            return ['apples', 'oranges', 'bananas'];
        }
    }
}]);
```

Here is the issue...

The selected item is getting into the input box, but foo variable next to input box is not updating.

Where is the mistake.

Please suggest...

Comment: Try changing `scope.$apply;` to `scope.$apply();`

Comment: Wow.. It worked...I might have come to SOF earlier.. Thanks CodeHater..

Comment: How to mark this comment as answer?

Comment: I have added my comment as answer below

Comment: And better if you change that two lines to: `scope.$apply(function() { scope.foo = ui.item.label; });` so the `scope.foo` assign will be executed inside angular context. That way angular can manage any error.

Comment: Thanks Jesus Rodriguez

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
scope.$apply;
```

to

```
scope.$apply(function(){
    scope.foo= ui.item.label;
});
```

Comment: This is a similar approach calling a function defined on the controller scope. It also covers an approach to set the value and label (name,id pair). 
http://www.ozkary.com/2015/09/angularjs-autocomplete-directive-with.html