# How to update ng-repeat variable using autocomplete?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui-autocomplete, angularjs-ng-repeat

Thanks to SOF for solving my last issue in angularjs and autocomplete.
[Angularjs with jquery auto complete not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19002571/angularjs-with-jquery-auto-complete-not-working)

Now, I have an issue of same type in ng-repeat...

In View

```
<tr data-ng-repeat="item in pagedItems">
                    <td title={{item.name}}>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td> <input type=text auto-complete ng-model="item.upload_status">
                    Upload status: {{item.upload_status}}</td>
                    <td title={{item.lat}}>{{item.lat}}</td>
                    <td title={{item.lon}}>{{item.lon}}</td>
                </tr>
```

In Directive

```
myapp.directive('autoComplete', function(autoCompleteDataService) {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, ctrl) {

        elem.autocomplete({

            source: autoCompleteDataService.getSource(), 

            select: function( event, ui ) {
                scope.$apply(function() { this.item.upload_status = ui.item.value; });
            },

            change: function (event, ui) {
                if (ui.item === null) {
                    scope.$apply(function() { scope.foo = null });
                }
            },
            minLength: 2
        });
    }
};
```

});

It is giving error as,

TypeError: Cannot set property 'upload_status' of undefined

Any idea to update upload_status is appreciated..

Comment: Try `scope.item.upload_status` instead of `this.item.upload_status`

Comment: Worked CodeHater.. thanks..How to study this angularjs.. it is difficult to start.. Please add as an answer..

Comment: You can go through the tutorial given at angularjs.org to get a clear understanding of the basics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`this.item.upload_status` should be `scope.item.upload_status`